# How to secure a SQFlite database with password protect embedded in the App?

Tags: flutter, sqflite

Secure the SQFlite database with password protect so it is only accessible by the App.

```
initDb() async {
    var databasePath = await getDatabasesPath();
    String path = join(databasePath, "Beta2.db");
    var theDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate)
    return theDb;
  }

  void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE Master(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, masterusername TEXT, masterpassword TEXT)");
    print("Created master username and password table")
    );
  }
```